# Traveling to Korea with special entry procedure because of COVID-19

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cellphones, south-korea, covid-19

According to the Korean government, a special entry procedure has been set for travellers from 5 European countries including The Netherlands. As an extension to some Asian countries.

[More info provided here by the Korean Embassy in The Netherlands on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/koreanembassynl/posts/3474848615865150)

> All travelers, both Korean and foreign nationals, from above countries are required to fill out Health Questionnaire and a Special Travel Record Declaration, which will be distributed onboard, including their contact information and address in Korea.
>
> At designated separate entry halls, immigration officials will collect
> the Health Questionnaire and will check travelers’ temperature,
> whether the travelers can be reached via the mobile phone number
> provided, and whether the travelers have downloaded ‘Self Diagnosis
> Mobile App’.

As far as I am aware, you can only rent or obtain a short duration Korean SIM after passing immigration and security. Therefor I will not have a Korean phone number when they check if my phone is reachable in the designated entry hall. Before swapping SIM cards (foreign SIM to Korean SIM).

I will be able to receive text messages and call through roaming, but after I swap my SIM I will have a different phone number. Will this be an issue for my upcoming travel?

Comment: Bring a dual-SIM phone with you and you can be reachable that way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.